# How to get Angular.js binding tags safely past Python's Jinja2?

Tags: angularjs

Python's server-side Jinja2 and JavaScript's client-side Angular should both be able to run on the same application but it's sort of troublesome when i.e.

```
<h1 class="object-attribute" ng-model="object" >{{ object.attribute }}</h1>
```

has to "make it past the Python" first without hiccups. How would one best disambiguate the Jinja2 from the Angular?

I know that I can nest the Angular within Jinja2's `{% raw %}{% endraw %}` tags as far as the server goes, but what way could I solve this on the client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider#!), you can change the symbols used for expressions.

> This feature is sometimes used to mix different markup languages, e.g. to wrap an Angular template within a Python Jinja template (or any other template language). Mixing templating languages is **very dangerous**. The embedding template language will not safely escape Angular expressions, so any user-controlled values in the template will cause Cross Site Scripting (XSS) security bugs!

```js
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});

customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
      this.label = "This binding is brought you by // interpolation symbols.";
```

```html
<div ng-app="customInterpolationApp" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
  //demo.label//
</div>
```

Comment: what's so dangerous about this?

Comment: @professorjones the quoted documentation is clear about this.  The template will not be sanitized, and malicious script injection is possible