# how to remove the special characters in html

Tags: python, html, angularjs

I am returning the url from python and trying to add that url to the table as hyper link.

Here is the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in results" class="text-center">
    <td style="font-size:12px" layout="row" layout-align="center">
        <a href="'{{a.plg}}'">
        {{a.date}}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the hyperlink i get is : https://seloid/%7B%7D
onstead of : https://seloid/doors/api/v1/solids/2017111/cube/

Comment: this looks to use more than html - html isn't a programming language so it doesn't handle the data - just outputs

Comment: This looks like you're using AngularJS, otherwise you'd get `%27%7B%7Ba.plg%7D%7D%27`...

Comment: yeah i am using AngularJS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Angular.js binding tags safely past Python's Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191768/how-to-get-angular-js-binding-tags-safely-past-pythons-jinja2/33192075#33192075)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Angular.js binding tags safely past Python's Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191768/how-to-get-angular-js-binding-tags-safely-past-pythons-jinja2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS, you need to use ng-href instead of href where there is an expression to evaluate. This ensures that it is evaluated before actually being bound to the href attribute.

In your example, `<a href="'{{a.plg}}'">` would become `<a ng-href="{{a.plg}}">` (note the single quotes are also removed).

Source: [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)